# Отправка широковещательных сообщений, используя netty

Tags: java, netty

Для реализации своего проекта решил использовать netty. Приложение должно действовать по такому алгоритму:

1. Клиент подключается к серверу и все время посылает необходимые данные для обновления.
2. Сервер обрабатывает эти данные и отсылает все изменения широковещательным сообщением для всех клиентов (что-то вроде UDP)

Проблема состоит в том, как такое реализовать? Если мы добавим новый Handler в наш PipeLine и унаследуем его от SimpleChannelInboundHandler, то у нас будут доступны только следующие методы:

1. channelActive - при подключении пользователя делаем что-то
2. channelRead0 - при получении сообщения делаем что-то
3. exceptionCaught - закрываем соединение.

И все, мы сюда не можем вставить како-либо широковещание. Выходом будет, если клиент будет постоянно посылать сообщения с запросом об обновлении, тогда в channelRead0 мы сможем отсылать обновления для конкретного клиента, но такая реализация не подходит.

При поисках ответа наткнулся на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527208/netty-write-to-all-connected-channels) вопрос, который подсказал, что необходимо использовать ChannelGroup.

Как реализовать что-то вроде myServer.sendBroadcast("message"); ?

Answer (score 3):

Покопавшись в документации и коде, обнаружил, что необходимо использовать ChannelGroup для этого. 
В метод channelActive нашего Handler-а вставляем код:

```
channels.add(ctx.channel());
```

Затем в нужном нам месте получаем ссылку на наш ChannelGroup channels и вставляем такой код:

```
for(Channel channel: channels)
channel.writeAndFlush(something);
```